# Terminal can't find my directory when I'm staring right at it

Tags: terminal

Ok guys, I'm at a loss. I'm just trying to open a directory, and it's showing in the list. But when I try to change to the directory, it says it doesn't exist (See screenshot). What's going on here?

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Wrap the folder name in `'`s eg. `cd 'hotel stuff'`

Comment: Welp... this is about as noob as it gets. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably escape the space: `cd hotel\ stuff` otherwise it tries to find `hotel` alone and then be left with another command `stuff`.